# GCP Cloud Functions to BigQuery - parquet support error

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a simple test `cloud function` where I create a `BigQuery` table and insert a value. The error I receive sounds like I need to import `pyarrow`, so I've tried doing that but I keep receiving the same error. When I run an equivalent script locally, there are no issues, the table is created, and I don't even need to import `pyarrow`. What am I missing here?

The `error`:

```
ImportError: Unable to find a usable engine; tried using: 'pyarrow', 'fastparquet'. pyarrow or fastparquet is required for parquet support
```

The `main.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pyarrow

def main_func(data, context):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': ['Success']})

    client = bigquery.Client()

    dataset_id = #removed here but specified in the real code
    dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_id)
    dataset.location = #removed here but specified in the real code
    dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset, exists_ok=True)
    print("Created dataset {}.{}".format(client.project, dataset.dataset_id))

    table_id = #removed here but specified in the real code

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("Test", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        ],
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    )

    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        df, table_id, job_config = job_config
    )

    job.result()
```

The `requirements.txt`:

```
pandas
google-cloud-bigquery
pyarrow
```

Comment: I found that Pandas does not detect any `pyarrow<0.4` because of compatibility issues, can you try adding `pyarrow>=0.4` in your requirements.txt

Comment: Dude! Just tried that, works fine! Add an answer and I'll accept it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with pyarrow version.  Pandas does not detect any `pyarrow<0.4` because of compatibility issues, therefore you should try adding `pyarrow>=0.4` in your `requirements.txt`.

[Pyarrow is not properly detected after importing ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/3744)